# Wouldn't a language without recursion still be non-finite at the level of discourse?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, recursion

[As per comments below, I have edited this question for greater clarity.]

I want to know whether a language without recursion, which would generate only a finite number of well-formed sentences, could still generate a potentially infinite amount of discourse.

As I understand it, the term "recursive" describes formal operations (including a grammar's generation of well-formed sentences and constituents) that can apply to their own output.   For example, the rules for forming relative clauses amount to a recursive operation, since relative clauses can be added to a noun phrase within some matrix relative clause.  Thanks to recursion, we have noun phrases such as the cat that ate the rat," "the cat that ate the rat that ate the cheese," "the cat that ate the rat that ate the cheese that attracted the roaches," and so on, *ad infinitum*.

When I say that recursion allows a grammar to generate a "potentially infinite" number of sentences, I mean that a formal description of the language's syntax would entail that the number of well-formed sentences in the language is infinite in principle.

When I say that a language without recursion is finite, I mean that such a language's syntax would entail that the number of well-formed sentences in the language would be finite.   This does NOT imply that a finite language couldn't generate enough sentences for its speakers to express themselves across contexts.   Neither does it mean that a finite language would necessarily be a simple one.   Dan Everett, a linguist who joined the Piraha-speaking community in South America to learn and study their language, has  claimed that Piraha is finite and has also described Piraha's verb formation as extremely complex.

Now so far, we've been talking only about sentences.  But we all know that people don't communicate in one-sentence telegrams.   We talk at length for various purposes.  In other words, we exhibit *discourse*.   AFAIK, a lot of human discourse is "potentially infinite."   In other words, in many types of discourse, an instance of such a type of discourse could continue indefinitely in principle.   Hence expressions like "That conversation will go on forever."

All this information prompted me to ask whether a language without recursion, which would have a finite number of sentences, could in principle allow discourse (such as conversations) that could in principle continue indefinitely.   I suspect that speakers of any language, finite or not, could go on talking forever in principle.  But I want to know if this is more than my suspicion.

Comment: The question and the current answer seem to depend on not trying to describe what is meant by recursion yet asserting that something about it is not true. You need to clarify your understanding of linguistic recursion and what you mean when you talk about it and terms like "non-finite". You could be talking at cross purposes or even creating a straw man argument.

Comment: AFAIK, "recursive" characterizes any operation that can be performed on its own output.   For example, relative clauses are recursive, since a relative clause can modify noun phrases in a matrix relative clause.   So we can have noun phrases such as "the cat that ate the rat," "the cat that ate the rat that ate the cheese," "the cat that ate the rat that ate the cheese that attracted the roaches," and so on.  AFAIK, a finite language is one whose grammar generates a finite number of well-formed sentences.  [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd from last comment]   AFAIK, a natural language that has recursion would generate a potentially non-finite number of well-formed sentences, owing to the fact that recursion in grammar could occur an arbitrarily large number of times.  However, a language without recursion would generate a finite number of well-formed sentences.   This does NOT mean that the language's grammar would not generate enough sentences for its speakers to express themselves.   Nor would it mean that the language would have a simple grammar.  Everett reports that Piraha's verbs are very complex.   [con'td]

Comment: If I don't have the concept of "recursive" or "finite" right, feel free to correct me.   However, be advised that a large number of posts on this list assume acquaintance with the terms used in said posts.   Witness the posts on computational linguistics, which I don't understand.  Yes, my post assumes that the reader knows what "recursion" and "finite" mean in this context.   I think that the post and its answer reflect this understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications James! But I think it would benefit your question and the audience who come to read it if you could rework all of these thoughts into a longer version of your question - because it is a good question but it has to be solidly asked. When well stated it will be easier for answerers to answer and to spot if there are any misconceptions.

Comment: I'm afraid that I have to admit that you're right.  I should have put the clarifications in the question for the benefit of a) those who came in late, and b) those who could correct any misconceptions that I have.   I'll try to be more careful in the future.  Would it be appropriate for me to edit the question according to the concerns that you have pointed out?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann That would be actually what you're supposed to do. :) Notify also the answerers with a brief comment that you've edited the question so that they can improve their answers accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have the recursion of syntactic dependencies in mind. Yes, I agree: a language can never be finite as long as you can produce it. Even saying the exact same thing twice or thrice or a hundred times can at least theoretically add or change meaning.

What those people you are probably thinking of mean is that you cannot have an infinite number of different *sentences* without some kind of sub-sentence recursion. That is to some extent true, but it seems to focus a bit too much on the sentence as a unit. Because I can say more or less the same thing... In shorter or different units. Another thing to consider is the following. Sentence boundaries are often a stylistic matter more tied to the following. Writing, rather than speech. They also are the following. Defined or chosen in somewhat arbitrary ways.

Comment: +1 for the self-referent answer.

Comment: Plus, of course, since humans are finite, no infinite-length sentences are possible. Unless by _sentence_ one means a string of letters, instead of an actual utterance. In which case it's not a linguistic question.

Comment: @jlawler: If if it means a string of letters, humanity and its products will in all likelihood one day perish, thereby ending all sentences. So we can't have infinite sentences anyway.

Comment: And in that case there won't have been an infinite number of them, either.

Comment: Dan Everett says exactly that Pirahã does use the method of several shorter sentences to express what would be expressed with one complex sentence in other languages, and that this is what it means to not have recursion.

Comment: Now Noam Chomsky has said firstly that all languages have recursion, but also that even if Pirahã doesn't have recursion that doesn't go against his theory. I do not know how he explains this though.

Comment: Please see my comment on the question about why I feel both this answer and the question are flawed without expressing what terms like "recursion", "finite", "non-finite" etc mean in this context.

Comment: Hi, Ceberus.   This is to let you know that I have edited my question for clarity, as suggested by hippietrail.   The editing is pretty extensive, so you may want to review your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've substantially fleshed out your question it's easy to answer.

> I want to know whether a language without recursion, which would generate only a finite number of well-formed sentences, could still generate a potentially infinite amount of discourse.

Yes of course! The linguistic theory of recursion is about syntax, within the sentence. It places no limits on what can happen among many sentences - discourse.

Answer (score -1):

Languages are defined as subset of Kleene closure of alphabet.So the subset may be recursive set or enumerably recursive set,or non-enumerably-recursive set,the last one is not recursive,and in fact,the last two are not recursive  in a strict sense.So,there are infinite languages that are not recursive.Or,there are as many  non recursive infinite language as real numbers.

Comment: What about the many languages that don't have an alphabet?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut,It is in the sense of formal language.You may can map a natural language without alphabet to a formal language,which is called encoding.Actually,for example,Chinese characters are a kind of alphabet that components of the language mapped.

Comment: What's Kleene closure?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann,en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star,it is from formal language theory,or logic.You know,Noam Chomsky has used a lot of idea and technics from mathematical logic.By the way ,I do not know who downvote my answer,I think the downvoter must have not known what the idea of recursion is :)

Comment: I downvoted it, for the same reason Gaston commented on. Linguistic recursion doesn't seem to have anything to do with writing systems at all.

Comment: @hippietrail，some background are necessary for one to understand recursion,I don't think I can make exposition of recursion in a comment or a post ,and recursion is a mathematical idea ,it is central idea of computability theory,so what you call linguistic recursion does not make sense.

Comment: @XL_at_China:   This is to let you know that I have edited my question for clarity, as suggested by hippietrail.   The editing is pretty extensive, so you may want to review your answer.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann,Since people asking the question and answering the question is somehow vague about the idea Recursion,I could not continue to discuss it.You guy could read Theory of recursive functions and effective computability by Hartley Rogers Jr.,that Chomsky had encourage him write,or some book about recursion like Matamathematics by Kleene for the central idea of several fields?Excuse me for not willing to discuss it again.